# in app purchase in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, in-app-purchase

i m confuse on restore iap,that how to restore it i have manage all the code how to restore it works fine.
the problem i face is where to call restore previous purchase 
1) To call in view did load for only once when app run first  time  ...

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

2)To call it before when user again click on purchase feature
if it fail to restore then call buy feature.

i m confuse that how to solve it ...
the other problem i face that when it try to restore the the previous purchase from different apple id (which actually not buy the feature ) then in simulator pop up window open connot connect to ITUNE ...

Answer (score 0):

To restore you have to provide a restore button so that whenever the user click the button all the purchases made by the user should be restored. In the `IBAction` method write these codes to restore

```
-(IBAction)restorePurchase:(id)sender
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

And remember one thing that in app purchase testing should be done on the devices not on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You have some option to call this out:

1. To call it first run of app :- keep a NSUserDefaults value to count the run time of the app like in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

   ```
   int i = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"usageCount"];
   i = i+1;

   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:i forKey:@"usageCount"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
   ```

From anywhere of the app, you can check and call

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"usageCount"]==0)
{
    //Call you action
}
```

For the first run, you can call the value of restore purchase.

2. You can keep a option/button in other/more/settings screen of your app which you can keep user feedback, ratings, in app purchase, restore purchase in a tableview.